# Как реализовать функцию "запомнить меня" на php?

Tags: php, mysql

Как реализовать функцию ? Знаю что нужно сохранить в куках сессию, но не знаю какие именно ? 
Или подскажите какую-то статью с простым примером ( я искал но ничего хорошего не нашел в интернете ).

***index.html***

```
<div align="center">
    <form name="form" action="home.php" method="post" class="form">
        <label>Логин</label>
          <br>
        <input class="inputlp" type="text" name="login" value="admin" >
          <br><br>
        <label>Пароль</label>
          <br>
        <input class="inputlp" type="password" name="pass" value="123456" >
          <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="input_button-" value="Войти">
    </form>
</div>
```

***home.php***

```
    session_start();  
     $login = trim($_POST['login']);
     $pass = trim($_POST['pass']); 

    require_once ("./config/admin_config.php");

        if(isset($login) && isset($pass)){
           $res = profile($login,$pass);
          if($res == 1){
            $_SESSION['register'] = $login;
            $register = $_SESSION['register'];
           }
        }
    ?>  

    <?php
        if($_SESSION['register']){
            require_once ("./html/home_page.php"); 
        } else {
            include("./error/error.php");
        }
```

Функция проверки в базе данных логина и пароля:

```
function profile($login,$pass)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin_profile` WHERE `login`='$login' AND `pass`=md5('$pass')");
    $res = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

не тестировал, но в принципе должно работать.
в таблицу admin_profile добавляем поле token

```
session_start();
$login = trim($_POST['login']);
$pass = trim($_POST['pass']);

require_once ("./config/admin_config.php");

function auth()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE['session'])) {

        $session = json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE['session']), true);

        if (array_key_exists('user_id', $session) && array_key_exists('token', $session)) {

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin_profile` WHERE `id` = '" . $session['id'] . "' AND `token` = '" . $session['token'] . "'");

            if (mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

    } else
        if (isset($_SESSION['register']))
            return true;
    return false;
}

function profile($login, $pass)
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin_profile` WHERE `login`='$login' AND `pass`=md5('$pass')");
    $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
    return $res;
}

if (isset($login) && isset($pass)) {
    $res = profile($login, $pass);
    if ($res) {

        if (isset($_POST['remember']) == 1) {

            $session = array(
                'user_id' => $res['id'],
                'token' => md5(uniqid(null, true)),
                );

            mysql_query("UPDATE `admin_profile` SET `token` = '" . $session['token'] . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $session['user_id'] . "'");

            setcookie('session', base64_encode(json_encode($session)), 31536000 + time(), '/');

        } else {

            $_SESSION['register'] = $login;
        }

    }
}


if (auth() == true) {
    require_once ("./html/home_page.php");
} else {
    include ("./error/error.php");
}
```

форма

```
<div align="center">
    <form name="form" action="home.php" method="post" class="form">
        <label>Логин</label>
          <br>
        <input class="inputlp" type="text" name="login" value="admin" >
          <br><br>
        <label>Пароль</label>
          <br>
        <input class="inputlp" type="password" name="pass" value="123456" >
          <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" checked> Запомнить меня 
          <br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" class="input_button-" value="Войти">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно ли как-то сделать проще, чтобы не создавать дополнительное поле `token` в базе данных, или это необходимо (или может это поле делает вход более безопасным ) ?

Comment: Хранити логин и пароль в сессии и не нужно поле `token`, но я бы так делать не стал. Не безопасно

Comment: @Petrovich можно логин и пароль(в мд5) хранить в куках. но это не безопасно.

Comment: @Solo_777 Данный код почему-то не работает, я так и не смог разобраться почему.